# selection.append / insert: d3 changes from v3 to v4 turns checkboxes into text fields

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As part of larger project, I have this function

```
  var setupSelections = function() {
  var form, labels, all, i;

  form = d3.select("#sample_names")
    .append("form");

  // Draw the labels
  labels = form.selectAll("label")
    .data(Names)
    .enter()
    .append("label")
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .insert("input")
    .attr({
        type: "checkbox",
        id: "CB_LABELS",
        class: "checkbox",
        name: function(d, i) {return i;},
        value: function(d, i) {return i;}
    })
    .property("checked", function(d, i) {
      if (i == 0) return 1
      if (i > 0) return 0
    });

  // Add event listeners
  all = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].addEventListener("change", updateSampleBOOL)
  }
} // End of setupSelections
```

In d3 v3, this code draws a series of labels `Names` with a checkbox next to them (on the right of the label).  In d3 v4, the labels are there but the check boxes turn into text fields, and then of course the part about "checked" fails since you can't set a text field to "checked".  I think this must be related to the changes described [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection):

> In 3.x, selection.append would always append the new element as the last child of its parent. A little-known trick was to use selection.insert without specifying a before selector when entering nodes, causing the entering nodes to be inserted before the following element in the update selection. In 4.0, this is now the default behavior of selection.append; if you do not specify a before selector to selection.insert, the inserted element is appended as the last child.

But I don't really understand how to use this to fix my code (if in fact this is the problem).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, yes, a duplicate I suppose but the title of my question may be more helpful.

Comment: Yes. But, for both questions, the best title would be *"D3 v4 problem when passing an object to .attr"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there was a small change in regards to setting multiple attributes from d3 v3 to d3 v4. Addressing this change produced the intended results in your code.

While in d3 v3 you could use selection.attr() to set multiple attributes, that is no longer the case. The proper method for setting multiple attributes at once is now:

```
   .attrs({
    type: "checkbox",
    id: "CB_LABELS",
    class: "checkbox",
    name: function(d, i) {return i;},
    value: function(d, i) {return i;}
})
```

But .attrs is not included in the default d3 v4 package, you can add:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

for access to that helper method.

From [d3 issues reporting on github](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2907):

> in the new version to assign multiple attributes on the same line you need to add d3-selection-multi. Now this functionality is not included with the main d3 import. The command is now called attrs instead of attr.

I believe there is similar changes in method behavior for selection.property() and selection.style() as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it!  And thank you for the careful explanation and details.